# Getting a job's build status as post-build variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to obtain the status of the Jenkins job in a variable during a Post-Build shell script?

I want to print out the message `Build Status is $BUILD_URL  :: $BUILD_STATUS`, where `$BUILD_STATUS` is the status of the current completed build (e.g. `ABORTED`, `SUCCESS`, or `FAILURE`).

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is quite dated, but I am able to use the [currentBuild](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals#currentBuild) variable, e.g.:

```
   post {
     always {
       emailext body: "See ${BUILD_URL}", recipientProviders: [requestor()], subject: "Jenkins: ${JOB_NAME}: Build status is ${currentBuild.currentResult}"
     }
   }
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for still posting this. Saved me hours!

Comment: This is the most simplest solution to implement.

Comment: [Link](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#global-variable-reference) to documentation, search for `currentBuild`.

Answer (score 8):

If you can invoke a python script as a post-build step, you can try something like this:

```py
import os, sys, json, codecs, urllib2

def main():
    url = "http://localhost:8080/job/jobName/lastBuild/api/json"
    try:
        fRead = urllib2.urlopen(url, None, 30); # 30 second timeout
    except:
        raise
    jsonResponse = json.loads(fRead.read());
    fRead.close();
    jobStatus = jsonResponse["result"]

main();
```

I have tested the url on my Jenkins and it works, but I haven't tested the script itself, so be wary. Obviously, substitute the port number and jobName as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.
But I keep getting the below error. 

urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Do I need to use a login and password to access the Jenkins url ? Any idea how I can overcome the above error.

Comment: You can try using an API token from Jenkins: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients
This article explains how to get and use the token. Then modify the url in the script as necessary.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to include the API TOKEN here is what worked for me:

```
BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --user USER:TOKEN_VALUE --silent $BUILD_URLapi/json | jq -r '.result')
```

which for me was:

```
BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --user robert:valueofmysecrettoken --silent $BUILD_URLapi/json | jq -r '.result')
```

Comment: Just using python to parse the JSON instead of jq: 

curl --silent --user USER:TOKEN $BUILD_URLapi/json | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]'

Answer (score 6):

Same as the answer from user3352495 but don't use any python dependencies.

I'm using jenkins own API to get the build status while the job is running, which works like a charm. Be aware that i'm using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) To parse the json response.

To get this to work simply add a shell script and execute the following command: `BUILD_STATUS=$(curl --silent ${BUILD_URL}api/json | jq -r '.result')`

[image: Execute shell step]

Which results in the following:

[image: Job console]

Comment: This is nice. You can append the URL with `?tree=result` to get something like `{"_class":"hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild","result":"SUCCESS"}` - I'm then just checking for the substring `SUCCESS` to determine the final status (as much as I like `jq` I don't feel like installing it on all the build slaves)

Answer (score 3):

On Jenkins 2.263.2, I was able to get the job status using the following variable.

```
${BUILD_STATUS}
```

Used it as a variable in a post-build plugin.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer since it took me way too long to find a decent solution for this.

You can use the url to check on ANY job from ANY pipeline. If the curl is nagging you about the self signed SSL cert make sure to add the -k option to skip the check.

Also don't forget that if you are running the jenkins server behind a security group, you'll need to allow access to the port you are running your jenkins from.

this was my solution running from a shell step in a pipeline

```
BUILD_STATUS=$(curl -k --user USER:apiToken --silent https://your.jenkins.url/job/yourJobName/lastBuild/api/json | jq -r '.result')
STATUS="SUCCESS"

            if [ $BUILD_STATUS == $STATUS ];
            then
                echo 'big yay'
                exit 0
            else
                exit 1
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ${currentBuild.currentResult} variable to know the status of build in post-build