# How to get jenkins build status in variable?

Tags: jenkins

I just installed Jenkins in ubuntu 16.04 and its working fine, But I want to create daily basis build a report like

Date time build name status

I am able to get all things except build status.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: Have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264431/jenkins-job-build-status

Answer (score 0):

Since the Build status is not defined until the bBuild process has finished, you are unable to get one, but using Trigger Parameterised Build allows you to call a second Jenkins job and set a variable to True of False depending on Trigger when build is option.
Then in you other Jenkins job, you can receive those Variables as parameters and write a nice little Case of if statement to react accordingly,