# Jenkins - Regex to match / not match words from logs in postbuild not working

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, testing, automation

I have a build in Jenkins which executes a script whenever there is a failure.
For what is considered as a failure, i have added my own conditions.

I want to check if in the logs i don't get a specific word or when i get some specific words (more than 1) and only then to proceed with the execution of the script.

I have tried these, but it doesn't work.

- matching: `.*abort.*Finished\s*:\s*FAILURE.*`

you can see that words exist in logs so this should had worked

[image: rules1]

- not matching: `^(?:(?!abort).)*$`

i searched for these words eg abort, unable , or timed out and they dont exist anywhere else in the logs apart from the screenshot, so i would expect this to work.

[image: rules2]

About the 'not matching', I am not sure up to which point it checks the logs for those regex eg if it checks until the end, then for sure those words exist in my logs as they get printed in order to show if regex was matched or not.

All my regex i have validated them btw through an online validator for Java, but i think the problem might be the new lines which i dont know how to include in my regex.

[image: matching]

[image: notmatching]

I have the latest version of Jenkins btw in case it matters and i am using this plugin: [Post build task](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task/)

Comment: Did you try `[\s\S]*abort[\s\S]*Finished\s*:\s*FAILURE[\s\S]*` Note that it will match the words in that order

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. and i can see again first this line: `07:56:21Agent is not connected --> aborting execution` and then at the end of the logs (AFTER the checks for the regex get printed in the logs - as shown in my first screenshot above) this: `07:56:21 Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Is the pattern run per line, or for the whole output once?

Comment: In the whole page. That’s why i mentioned that I don’t think i check for new lines with my rege

Comment: Try getting the result from Jenkins instead of parsing the logs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264431/getting-a-jobs-build-status-as-post-build-variable